# .cab file size grows rapidly when adding file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5, .net-micro-framework, cabwiz

I have a deployment project, which creates a .cab file of my App for installing it on a Windows Mobile 6.5 PDA. 
Recently I made the app multillingual. Because of the [CabWiz bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359445/localization-with-net-compact-framework)(concerning localization), I added my resource files manually via the `Add` / `File...` functionality.

Now the size of the created .cab file rises enormously.
First, the .cab file was less than 500KB. Now, after adding 1 resource file(about 50KB) the size ist about 2.4MB!

Because of the bigger size I get `OutOfMemoryExcepitons` during the OTA Update in my App.

Does anyone know, how to prevent that enormous increase of size of the .cab file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know what VS always does when using the Cab Setup project, I create my cabs manually. You should open and browse the cab for example in the trial of OCP Software WinCE Cab Manager or the free software msceInf. I assume the file is added multiple times or the Cab was compressed and now is save uncompressed.

Comment: I recognized, that the deploy project additionally adds the `mscorlib.dll` into that folder where I put that resource dll file. When I open the generated .cab file with WinZip, I can see a `mscorlib.002` with 500KB and a `mscorlib.001` with 4.5MB!!

Comment: Possibly your resource dll has a dependency on mscorlib.whatever. Try to remove the added mscorlib dlls off the setup project. How do you add the resource.dll?

Comment: In addition to the previous comments (removing dependencies that are unnecessary if already on your devices), don't forget to use the `compress` setting during CabWiz process