# Add resx to cab file

Tags: c#, compact-framework, resx, cab

I have an app on Windows Embedded which uses .resx files to translate the app to different languages. 
Also I create an installation .cab file but I can't include the resx file to this cab.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks for any tip

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You'd not told us how you're trying to add the file.  Are you using a custom INF file and just calling CABWIZ or are you using a Visual Studio Installer Project?
2. What have you done to try to include the file?
3. Most importantly, a RESX file does *not* contain the run-time resources and you rarely would deploy it. The RESX resources get compiled into a `*.resource.dll` assembly, that is typically in a subfolder with a name for the locale (e.g. `en-us` or `fr-ca`).  You need to deploy those files/folders which is challenging because CABWIZ doesn't allow duplicate file names (and all resources have the same file name, just different folders).  That scenario is handled by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672752/culture-specific-string-resource-dll-not-working-in-net-compact-framework-when).

Comment: I was using Visual Studio Installer and I could not add the resx file to it. The only way I was able to deploy those files was through 'implement' option. Now I'm changing my translate to a XML file, I guess using resx file wasn't a good idea